# Changing property of image by not sretching or changing how it looks

Tags: html, css

I have a transparent image (an icon) and some text right above it. Now, when you hover on that text, it should turn orange. Now, when you hover on the top region of the text, it's turning orange. However, when you hover on the bottom region of the text, it doesn't turn orange because the image occupies that area. I don't want this to happen. I should be able to hover wherever on the text and it should turn orange, but now, I can only hover on the top of the text, because the image doesn't occupy that text, but it does occupy the bottom region, so when you hover there, the text doesn't turn orange.

The only problem is that I can't move the image or the text left or right or up or down, because that will completely ruin my design layout. Furthermore, I can't even change the width or height of the image because that will stretch the image and change how it looks. Taking both of these aspects into consideration, I want the image to remain exactly the same; not to look different by not stretching it; and hover anywhere on the text for it to turn orange. With no other options, I'm puzzled. Here's my code:

```
<div style="margin-left: 715px; position: fixed; font-family: 'Rajdhani'">
  <h2 style="margin-left: 440px; margin-top: 206px; cursor:pointer; padding: 5px; position: fixed" class="textShare">Share</h2> // The text
 </div>
 <div style="position: fixed; margin-left: 1063px; margin-top: 285px">
   <img class="textupvote" id="textUpvoteImg" src="img/upvote.png" alt="upvote" onclick="changetextUpvote()" style="width: 100px; margin-bottom: 28px; cursor: pointer">  // Ignore this image; below image is what I'm talking about
   <img class="textdownvote" id="textDownvoteImg" src="img/downvote.png" alt="downvote" onclick="changetextDownvote()" style="width: 120px; margin-top: -12px; position: fixed; cursor: pointer"> // The image
 </div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should really have your CSS in an external style sheet, not inline like you have.

Irregardless, this can be achieved using `z-index`.

For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/4qgknh0c/

```
.wrapper {
  postion: relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: red;
}

.text:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.image {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. So wrapper is the div? And is the padding for the image absolutely necessary?

Comment: And this isn't working. Everything is all over the place. And I tested out your JS Fiddle, it's working without z-index or position:absolute as well. Only problem is, mine isn't..